# Where does Microsoft implement Observer in .NET

Tags: .net, observer-pattern

What areas of the .NET framework implement the observer pattern?

Comment: [IObserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx)? Are you asking for concrete examples of classes that use this? Why / what areas of the framework are you interested in?

Comment: Pretty much anyplace that uses events.

Comment: C# event is the built-in observer implementation

Comment: @JoeWhite right - I should have phrased the question better.  Below Thomas provided an example of where those are used in the framework - this is more of what I was wanting.  I want to be able to point people I work with to real implemented examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) are clearly an implementation of the observer pattern (although not exactly the in the same form, since it relies on a specific language feature).

[Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) are another example

Comment: thanks!  I knew events was the pattern, I guess I should have phrased more towards examples where events are implemented  Reactive extensions...good example, I'll use this... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

WPF/WinForms makes heavy use of the Observer Pattern with the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) event, particularly around data binding.

Comment: Not just WPF actually, it is also used in Windows Forms data binding

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I was using WPF as a specific example; but right.

Answer (score 1):

Here: [Exploring the Observer Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx) and: [`IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx).